# Find index of a substring in a string, with start index specified

Tags: string, go

I know there is `strings.Index` and `strings.LastIndex`, but they just find the first and last. Is there any function I can use, where I can specify the start index? Something like the last line in my example.

Example:

```
s := "go gopher, go"
fmt.Println(strings.Index(s, "go")) // Position 0
fmt.Println(strings.LastIndex(s, "go")) // Postion 11
fmt.Println(strings.Index(s, "go", 1)) // Position 3 - Start looking for "go" begining at index 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's an annoying oversight, you have to create your own function.

Something like:

```
func indexAt(s, sep string, n int) int {
    idx := strings.Index(s[n:], sep)
    if idx > -1 {
        idx += n
    }
    return idx
}
```

Answer (score 6):

No, but it might be simpler to apply strings.Index on a slice of the string

```
strings.Index(s[1:], "go")+1
strings.Index(s[n:], "go")+n
```

See [example](http://play.golang.org/p/NlZwubOQnT) (for the case where the string isn't found, see [OneOfOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/145587/oneofone)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25837141/6309)), but, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837030/find-index-in-string-with-startindex/25837128#comment40427491_25837141) by [Dewy Broto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4017302/dewy-broto), one can simply test it with a ['`if`' statement including a **simple statement**](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements):
(also called ['`if`' with an initialization statement](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#if))

```
if i := strings.Index(s[n:], sep) + n; i >= n { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: This would return n - 1 if the string wasn't found. http://play.golang.org/p/N5McWNY8t0